# How determine which netw. Interface is used with java

Tags: java, linux, networking, network-programming, network-interface

I want to know if it's possible to determine which network interface is used by a java code.

For example I could use an inputstream with an URL object to download the source code. But I want the traffic to go through the interface wlan0 for example and not eth0. Is it possible to check which interface is currently used for the java network process?

Comment: Routing is not up to the Java VM or even to the application running in it. When traffic is going through the wrong route the runing must be configured the wrong way on the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check with interface was used you can take a `tcpdump` of all the network traffic in and out of the machine and use a tool like wireshark to view it.   A simpler approach is to look at the number of Tx and Rx packets in `ifconfig -a` to see which interface was used.

Comment: I want to check it within java. Like if(network.getinterface().toString().equals("wlan0")) then do something else do nothing. Just an example

Comment: I guess a simple approach is not possible

Comment: @F91 the problem is that you can give a hint to the OS as to which network interface to use but it can be free to send it how it likes.  Recent version of Windows is String Hosting so you can control it but, for Linux you have no control.